# Canvas getImageData returns wrong pixel color value in FF

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

Here is the test https://jsfiddle.net/mgevlich/fqxbntyj/22/

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var pix = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height).data;
var ind = (y * img.width + x) << 2;
return [pix[ind], pix[ind + 1], pix[ind + 2], pix[ind + 3]];
```

If you touch green area you'll find 1 in R channel in FF, BUT there is no 1 value, only green! It happens in FF only. Does anybody have a guess what is wrong with this image?))
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't repro FF66 macOs But your code is incredibly inefficient. Here is an update: https://jsfiddle.net/L2qkat09/

Comment: Thank you)), but no luck in FF. Unexpected ONE in R channel is still here.